# How to catch exceptions/errors in addon.cc(using Nan)

Tags: node.js, openssl, v8, n-api

Using Nan in addon.cc to invoke OpenSSL layer methods for decryption/signing/verification from NodeJS.

When trying to hit the methods again and again in OpenSSL from NodeJS - getting decryption/verification errors - if these errors are hit for several number of times, its causing the server to crash.
How can the errors/exception that is crashing the server be caught somehow in addon.cc?

Below is the sample of the exceptions that we saw during the server crash:

```
Error: 8668943040:error:21070073:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_dataDecode:no recipient matches certificate:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_doit.c:491:
8668943040:error:21072077:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_decrypt:decrypt error:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:500:

Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at TLSSocket._emitTLSError (_tls_wrap.js:893:10)
    at TLSWrap.onerror (_tls_wrap.js:416:11) {
  library: 'PKCS7 routines',
  function: 'PKCS7_dataDecode',
  reason: 'no recipient matches certificate',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_NO_RECIPIENT_MATCHES_CERTIFICATE'
}
```

We tried to make use of Nan::try_catch but it did not help in catching the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exception that you can catch - it is an `error` event in a stream handler. It detects a failure and raises an exception and raises an exception in an asynchronous context because you don't have an `error` handler installed. These exceptions are uncatchable because they don't have an enclosing block.

Register an `error` handler on the `TLSSocket` - this error is not coming from your `addon.cc`.